# SSIS Data Flow to CSV incorrectly formats string of numbers to exponential notation

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have an SSIS Package (SQL Server 2008 R2) that creates a .csv file from an OLE DB Source using a SQL SELECT. Using the Preview.. I can see that it has got the first column, Source_Txn_Id, correctly formatted. It is a varchar(35) of all numbers, that can start with a zero. It's used as a unique reference.

However, I can't set-up the Flat File Connection Manager Editor to correctly display this in the CSV file. Once created it/Excel has formatted the first column as exponential notation. Also the value has dropped any leading zeros.

Do I need to use a Derived Column or otherwise to fix this, or somehow update the Cell format after the file has been generated?

thanks

Comment: View it in notepad, not excel. You'll find Excel is applying formatting and it is perfectly fine in the CSV file.

Comment: In other words a derived column won't help. Is this file for purposes of viewing in Excel? If so prepend your data with a `'` to tell Excel its a string